# retrieve data to html block using python flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have code which can find and print nearest hospitals:

`python`:

```
@app.route('/check', methods=['POST'])
def check():
    place = 'Checking nearest hospitals..'
    API_KEY = 'MY_KEY'

    google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY) 

    query_result = google_places.nearby_search( 
            lat_lng ={'lat': 40.4222532, 'lng': 49.8035278}, 
            radius = 5000, 
            types =[types.TYPE_HOSPITAL]) 

    if query_result.has_attributions: 
        print (query_result.html_attributions)

    for place in query_result.places: 
        print(place.name)
    return render_template('check.html', place=place.name)
```

`default.html`:

```
<form action="/check" method="POST">
    <button type="check" class="btn btn-primary">Nearest Hospitals</button>   

</form>
```

`hospital.html`

```
<div class="box">
     <p>{{ place.name }}</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can see only one hospital in my html box, but in console there are many hospitals prints. How to print every hospital in the box as in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to send the entire query instead of just a place name

```
python:
    return render_template('hospital.html', places=query_result.places)
```

you can print them all in the loop

```
hospital.html
<div class="box">
   {% for place in places %}
        <p>{{ place.name }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Man, but could you clarify why with `{% for place in query_result.places %}` instead of  `{% for place in places %}` in html it did not work?

Comment: Because we put the query in the places variable